# Ocaml: Syntax Error

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to figure out why this is not working, I get Error: Syntax Error. Did I miss a ";" somewhere ?

```
let way_tags_to_hashtbl way =
  let hashtbl = Hashtbl.create 1 in
  let rec way_tags_to_hashtbl_partial list = match list with
    | a::list' -> Hashtbl.add hashtbl (a.k, a.v); way_tags_to_hashtbl_partial list'
    | a::[] -> Hashtbl.add hashtbl (a.k, a.v)
    | [] -> [];
  way_tags_to_hashtbl_partial way.wtag; hashtbl
;; <------ ERROR HERE
```

Thank you.

Comment: p.s. `let rec way_tags_to_hashtbl_partial list = match list with` can be written as `let rec way_tags_to_hashtbl_partial = function`

Comment: p.p.s the `a::[]` case will never be reached, because `a::list'` already covers it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing an `in` about two lines up:

```
let way_tags_to_hashtbl way =
  let hashtbl = Hashtbl.create 1 in
  let rec way_tags_to_hashtbl_partial list = match list with
    | a::list' -> Hashtbl.add hashtbl (a.k, a.v); way_tags_to_hashtbl_partial list'
    | a::[] -> Hashtbl.add hashtbl (a.k, a.v)
    | [] -> [] in (* !!! HERE !!! *)
  way_tags_to_hashtbl_partial way.wtag; hashtbl
;;
```

I don't have ocaml installed on this machine, can't check...

Comment: @amadan : if you want to check some ocaml code, you can use the [online toplevel][1], you don't need to install anything.


  [1]: http://try.ocamlpro.com/